# Polymer Dart - Google App engine TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, dart-polymer

I am trying to deploy my app to Google App Engine but I have this error

`< template if="{{!has_unique}}">` 
TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char u'!' at 8991

[image]

I think it has something to do with the Python Framework and Darts Polymer templates possibly conflicting?

Does anyone else know about this and can think of a solution?

Update: It seems to be trying to parse my Dart templates as Jinja???

Update 2: It was the Dart  tags. Wrap the whole build HTML in 
        `<!--{% raw %}--> <html></html> <!--{% endraw %}-->` 
to ignore any Jinja unsupported syntax

Comment: Do you also use Jinja for server side templating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Jinja is the problem you can use {% raw %} ...... {% endraw %} to escape.

Comment: Thanks! I have wrapped my whole build HTML in <!--{% raw %}--> generated src <!--{% endraw %}--> which fixes the Jinja parsing and ignores it from Dart